# How do i get the key name out of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [Super Place] => CC Verse Go 0
        [Demented Place] => CC Verse Stop 1
    )
```

And it want to be able to loop through the array and insert the data into a DB. It's easy enough looping through and finding the value based on the Key, but I also need to insert the Key itself.  Can I get the Key name using the value or some other method?

Any help is appreciated.

Many Thanks,
K

Comment: this will be single or multiple arrays like [0],[1] etc ?

Comment: use the [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php). you will search the associative array using the value and you will get the key in return

Comment: `foreach ($arr as $ar){foreach ($ar as $key=>$value){$key will be  "Super Place"... so on and $value will be "CC Verse Go 0".... so on correspondingly}}`

Comment: @MahmoodRehman it's multiple arrays [0],[1],[2],...[200]

Comment: @Anant  Many Thanks! That did it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in below way:-

```
<?php

$array = Array(0 => Array
    (
        'Super Place' => 'CC Verse Go 0',
        'Demented Place' => 'CC Verse Stop 1'
    ));

foreach ($array as $arr){
   foreach ($arr as $key=>$value){
      echo $key.'= '.$value;
      echo PHP_EOL;
   }
}
```

Output:-https://eval.in/686393

Answer (score 3):

Ok let me show both code for you.
If you have single array then try like this :

```
array = array(
    'Super Place' => 'CC Verse Go 0',
    'Demented Place' => 'CC Verse Stop 1'
);

foreach($array as $key=> $val){
    echo 'Key :' . $key. ', Value' . $val. '';
}
```

And if you have  multiple arrays like dynamic then try like this :

```
foreach ($ary as $newarr){
foreach($newarr as $key=> $val){
        echo 'Key :' . $key. ', Value' . $val. '';
    }
}
```